# Is TEMPO firmly planned to be launched?

Tags: geostationary, earth-observation

The Tropospheric Emissions: Monitoring POllution (TEMPO) instrument (see [Smithsonian Institute](http://tempo.si.edu/overview.html), [EO Portal](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/t/tempo), or [WMO Oscar](https://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/satellites/view/590)) is supposed to measure air pollution over North America from a geostationary orbit.  It is in that sense comparable to [Copernicus Sentinel-4 Ultraviolet, Visible, Near-infrared (UVN)](https://earth.esa.int/web/guest/missions/esa-future-missions/sentinel-4) (to be launched on EUMETSATs Meteosat Third Generation (MTG)-S in 2023) or [GEO-Kompsat 2](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/content/-/article/geo-kompsat-2) Geostationary Environment Monitoring Spectrometer (GEMS).  UVN and GEMS are confirmed to happen but I can't find a recent firm status on TEMPO.  Does TEMPO have a confirmed platform?  Apparently, the instrument has been built and delivered to NASA.  The last I've seen is [an unconfirmed proposal for it to fly on a commercial satellite in 2022](https://spacenews.com/maxar-to-install-nasa-pollution-sensor-on-commercial-satellite/), but this is scarce on details.

[image: NO₂ from TROPOMI]
NO₂ from TROPOMI.  *Source: [Smithsonian Institute](http://tempo.si.edu/overview.html), © KNMI/IASB/ESA/SAO*.

Comment: That's odd... I wonder if GEMS isn't stationed over India enough to get correct readings, I'd expect India to have more red spots. Maybe not though. May ask a question follow up about how the parts that aren't covered are approximated.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn None of those satellites are flying yet!  The data in this figure are from polar orbiting satellites, which observe globally but only once a day, whereas the geostationary satellites will observe continuously but only in the area of focus.  I don't know the chemistry explaining why the figure looks the way it does.

Comment: "is X flying" can be interpreted in several ways due to ambiguity of the word choice and grammar. I would advise to rephrase.

Comment: @user2705196 Fair enough.  I have rephrased.